# Partial Update Document without script Elasticsearch

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch

I am using the following code for partial update

```
POST /website/blog/1/_update
{
   "script" : "ctx._source.views+=1"
}
```

is there any alternative way I can achieve the same thing. because I don't want to change anything in
groovy script because last time I changed the settings and my server was compromised.

So someone please help me with the solution or some security measures if there is no work around.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot dynamically change a field value without using a script.

[You can use file-based scripts](https://www.elastic.co/blog/running-groovy-scripts-without-dynamic-scripting) though, which means that you can disable dynamic scripting (default in ES 1.4.3+) while still using scripting in a safe, trusted way.

```
config/
  elasticsearch.yml
  logging.yml
  scripts/
    your_custom_script.groovy
```

You could have the script store:

```
ctx._source.views += your_param
```

Once stored, you can then access the script by name, which bypasses dynamic scripting.

```
POST /website/blog/1/_update
{
  "script": "your_custom_script",
  "params" : {
    "your_param" : 1
  }
}
```

Depending on the version of Elasticsearch, the `script` parameter is better named (e.g., ES 2.0 uses "inline" for dynamic scripts), but this should get you off the ground.